# @OneToOne annotation within composite key class is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Maybe somebody can clarify what is wrong with the code below. When I create one-to-one association within embedded class (it is composite primary key) like in the code below:

```
@Entity
public class Test {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TestId id;

    @Embeddable
    public static class TestId implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1950072763330622759L;

        @OneToOne(optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "linkedTable_id")
        private LinkedTable linkedTable;

    }
    ..........
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
--------------------------------------------

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:1867)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1286)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1211)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:235)
    ... 26 more
```

What is interesting why the sample above works if I change association type to many-to-one and doesn't work with one-to-one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't aware this was possible but, according to the Hibernate Annotation reference documentation, it is (this is Hibernate specific though):

> #### [2.2.3.2.1. @EmbeddedId property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1037)
>
> (...)
>
> While not supported in JPA, Hibernate
>   lets you place your association
>   directly in the embedded id component
>   (instead of having to use the
>   `@MapsId` annotation).
>
> ```
> @Entity
> class Customer {
>   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
>   boolean preferredCustomer;
> }
>
> @Embeddable
> class CustomerId implements Serializable {
>   @OneToOne
>   @JoinColumns({
>     @JoinColumn(name="userfirstname_fk", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
>     @JoinColumn(name="userlastname_fk", referencedColumnName="lastName")
>   }) 
>   User user;
>   String customerNumber;
> }
>
> @Entity 
> class User {
>   @EmbeddedId UserId id;
>   Integer age;
> }
>
> @Embeddable
> class UserId implements Serializable {
>   String firstName;
>   String lastName;
> }
> ```

And with the code you provided, the following snippet just works for me:

```
LinkedTable linkedTable = new LinkedTable();
linkedTable.setId(1l);
session.persist(linkedTable);
session.flush();

Test.TestId testId = new Test.TestId();
testId.setLinkedTable(linkedTable);
Test test = new Test();
test.setId(testId);
session.persist(test);
session.flush();
```

Tested with Hibernate EM 3.4.0.GA, Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA and Hibernate Core 3.3.0.SP1.

If it doesn't work for you, can you provide a bit more code allowing to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Dear Pascal, thanks for the answer. I have checked it with the Hibernate only version and indeed it works. For now, I don't know what is exactly causes the problem. I use Hibernate + JPA couple and I think that problem is JPA then. I am gonna check it.

Comment: @Graffinych: Well, as I wrote, I tested this with Hibernate Entity Manager (i.e. Hibernate + JPA).